# How to configure debug and release log level for Retrofit?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit, android-debug

I use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) in my Android project. While developing I enable full log output for the `RestAdapter` as follows:

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
```

When I bake a release the log level is set to `RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE` for obvious reasons.

I would like to automatically switch this setting based on the build/folder architecture:

```
.
├── app
│   └── src
│       ├── debug
│       ├── main
│       └── release
```

How can I move `RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL` into `app/src/debug` and `RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE` into `app/src/release` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` flag, which is automatically set to true for debug builds and false for release builds.

I do this like so:

```
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL : RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
```

Comment: Thank you. The only thing I do no like is that the "configuration" is not in one place such as in `res/values/config.xml`.

Answer (score 12):

A better way to do this is via the `build.gradle` file as such:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField 'retrofit.RestAdapter.LogLevel', 'RETROFIT_LOG_LEVEL', 'retrofit.RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL'
    }

    release {
        buildConfigField 'retrofit.RestAdapter.LogLevel', 'RETROFIT_LOG_LEVEL', 'retrofit.RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE'
    }
}
```

Then in code do this:

```
mRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("http://something.com")
    .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.RETROFIT_LOG_LEVEL)
    .build();
```

This way there is no check at runtime, only at compiletime